# Access WP8/Win8 in-app purchase info from web application

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Phone app with in-app purchases.

Is it possible for me to access my app users in-app purchases state from a ASP.NET web site where they log in with the same account as they have on their phone?

I would like to check if user A bought feature B to decide what to show on the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to send the info about purchases from the app to your server when users buy something.